# Webpack babel build fails on arrow function parse

Tags: webpack, babeljs

After including npm package `react-monaco-editor` into my project, my webpack build started to fail.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-monaco-editor/src/diff.js 108:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (108:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   }
|
>   assignRef = (component) => {
|     this.containerElement = component;
|   };
 @ ./node_modules/react-monaco-editor/src/index.js 2:0-38 4:0-53
 @ ./Scripts/Editor/Components/CodePreview.tsx
 @ ./Scripts/Editor/Components/Editor.tsx
 @ ./Scripts/Editor/main.tsx
```

I'm using babel loader and here is my `.babelrc` file.

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/react",
        "@babel/typescript",
        "@babel/env",
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
    ]
}
```

My first thought when I saw this error was that I was missing arrow function plugin that after adding it the error persisted and since I'm already using `transform-class-properties` plugin which most related solutions refer to I don't know what else to try.

**Edit:**

So I've change my rule for processing files to include `.js` files

```
{ test: /\.[jt]sx?$/, loader: "babel-loader" },
```

And now I'm getting the error from babel-loader

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-monaco-editor/src/diff.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Projects\Michelangelo\Main_backend\MichelangeloWeb\node_modules\react-monaco-editor\src\diff.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (108:13):
```

So I've downloaded the suggested `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` and now my `.babelrc` looks like this

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/react",
        "@babel/typescript",
        "@babel/env",
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    ]
}
```

But I keep getting the same error.

Comment: have you got both `transform-class-properties` and `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` in your `package.json`? I see that you corrected it, but did you also remove every reference to non-@babel package(s)?

Comment: yes I did. Since writing this question I have swapped to package `react-monaco-editor-ts` which doesn't give me this error and now I have pretty similar one directly from `monaco` demanding `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` although I have it installed and included in babel plugins.

Answer (score 0):

This adjustment should work for this issue:

```js
{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/, // Transform all .js and .jsx files required somewhere with Babel
      // react-monaco-editor uses arrow function, need to parse
      exclude: /node_modules(?!\/react-monaco-editor)/, 
      use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: options.babelQuery,
      },
}
```

Source: https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor/issues/259